# @font-face not working for me

Tags: css, font-face

Having trouble getting the @font-face feature to work in my css

using the following code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: bigCaslon;
    src: url(http://www.mywebsite.com/web/wp-content/font/BigCaslon.ttf);
    font-weight:400;
}
```

and then setting the font to this in the same css:

```
font-family: 'bigCaslon';
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

ok so i changed the code to the following:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('../web/wp-content/font/BigCaslon.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('../web/wp-content/font/BigCaslon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('../web/wp-content/font/BigCaslon.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('../web/wp-content/font/BigCaslon.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('../web/wp-content/font/BigCaslon.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }

font-family: 'MyWebFont';
```

but still no luck. i created the other font formats also

Comment: Did you try `font-family: 'bigCaslon';`, so with the `'` around it in your `@font-face`?

Comment: What does the url give you when you fill in the url in the urlbar ? Does that work?

Comment: hi, just made that change there and still no luck

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745424/custom-font-face-css/22745476#22745476

Comment: it says "nothing found" - what should it show?

Comment: Chances are your path is incorrect. Open up your console when you load your page and I'll bet you'll see some 404 errors when the browser was requesting the fonts. To ultimately solve this, we'd need your directory structure and/or a link to your website.

Comment: http://www.lofthairstudio.ie/web/wp-content/font/BigCaslon.ttf

Comment: what should the path to the font display in browser

Comment: @gussy81 - no it doesn't. By looking at your CSS file, and where you are saying your font is located, then your path to your font in the CSS file should be `../../fonts/BigCaslon.eot`. But you should also be putting your fonts in your theme directory, not just your wp-content directory.

Comment: you are a gent Adam thank you very much - was the extra ../

Answer (score 1):

You can't just use a single `ttf` and expect it to work. Most browsers use `woff` font files to render custom fonts. Additionally, for complete browser support you need to use the [BulletProof @font-face syntax](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/further-hardening-of-the-bulletproof-syntax):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }
```

You can generate `eot`,`woff`, and `svg` files from a `ttf` or `otf` file using [FontSquirrel's Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

**EDIT TO ANSWER COMMENT**

The font files don't have to be in the same directory, as long as the path is correct.
For example, my directory structure usually looks like this:

```
assets/
    css/
       style.css
    fonts/
       family/
           family.ttf
           family.svg
           family.woff
           family.eot
```

and in that case the path to my font in my CSS would look like this:

```
url('../fonts/family/family.eot')
```

Comment: ok i will give this a go. should the font be located in the same directory as the css file?

Comment: i had a go but didnt work for me. ive posted my new code above - seems to be what you advised

Answer (score 0):

ok so adam finally got me there in the end and this was my solution

i put the fonts all in a folder called fonts in the main directory of my ftp and used the following syntax in my master css file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('../../font/BigCaslon.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('../../font/BigCaslon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('../../font/BigCaslon.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('../../font/BigCaslon.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('../../font/BigCaslon.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }
```

and then i referenced the font:

```
font-family: 'MyWebFont';
```

thanks everybody for getting me going in the right direct and respect to Adam!!