# my fonts are not working when I open my website in firefox

Tags: css, html, firefox, fonts, font-face

I am using font-face, and the fonts AntennaCond and Roboto. these two fonts are working in Safari and chrome, but they are crashing in Firefox.

Here is my website: http://www.ux-pm.com

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: which font type you are using .woff ?

Comment: .suit for AntennaCond and .ttf for Roboto

Comment: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator check this link

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check path of fonts in css file also you need different types (.ttf, .woff, .eot, .svg) of fonts to render across browsers.

1) websites like http://www.font2web.com/ or http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator where you can upload font and it will give you ready made folder structure with css and custom fonts applied.

2) **[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745424/custom-font-face-css/22745476#22745476)** similar question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: well I used fontsquirrel, and added ttf, .eot and .woff types in my code, but still no result.. any idea?